# Call Javascript function from gridview RowCommand

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Does anyone know how to call Javascript functions from a Gridview RowCommand Event in ASP?

i need to call function to receive rowindex but i didn't know how to call javascript function from rowcommand

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it using ScriptManager

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('File already exists.');", true);
```

In place of alert you can call the javascript function.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void myGV_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "click1")
        {
           GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

           int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex; 
           // now call the javascript function
           Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "modalDialog", "CallJavaScriptFunction("+RowIndex +");", true);
        }

        if (e.CommandName == "click2")
        {
            Do something cool ... 
        }
    }
```

Comment: i got this message : Unable to cast object of type 'Xxx.XXXXX.Classes.GridViewTemplate.ExtendedGridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton'

Comment: @ZenIskan what is the exception??

Comment: seem problem with these (imagebutton) i didn't use button template. i'm using edit in extendedGridView template :

http://pastebin.com/YHQzYDAS

Comment: You should have a button or link to click which goes u into the RowCommand event. Replace your button or link with ImageButton. I was giving you the example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a JavaScript function this may help you.

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Call my function","func()",true);

Just replace func with your function name..

if you use jquery in your script don't forget to add the source jquery file.